# install NuSMV 2.6 tool on windows 64bit

Tags: verification, model-checking

How can I install NuSMV 2.6 tool on windows? I try but I can not, I don't know how can I install it. should I install any program before install NuSMVV?

Answer (score 4):

It is enough to:

1. Download a binary NuSMV-2.6.0-win64.tar.gz from: http://nusmv.fbk.eu/NuSMV/download/getting_bin-v2.html
2. Extract all files.
3. Study: http://nusmv.fbk.eu/NuSMV/userman/v26/nusmv.pdf
4. Execute NuSMV-2.6.0-win64\bin\NuSMV.exe accordingly